# Can't get java to use more than one core

Tags: java, concurrency, profiling

I'm working on a concurrency assignment that involves parallelizing a problem for performance. The problem involves a fair amount of blocking i/o so for my report I want to use and compare cpu usage of various approaches.

I'm new to profiling and I've started off with Java's vitual vm, but even with multiple threads running a tight loop with no blocking I can't seem to get above 50% cpu usuage. This would seem to be that only one of my two cores is being used.

How do I get my threads to use both cores? I've tried both manually creating threads and using the executor framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a problem with your code. Unfortunately, you haven't posted any code, which makes it hard to see where the problem is. Please post a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem...

Comment: The total CPU usage is governed by the OS - not directly by the JVM - so may be the OS is allowing JVM to use 50% of the CPU , within which your threads are being efficient ( in their concurrent usage ) - Can you see the Visual VM showing 2 threads running with so much of CPU each % ?

Comment: Perhaps you actually do use the cores, yet all threads but one is actually waiting for an IO operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your code is doing, but this manages to put all my cores up to 100%...

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test task = new Test();
        int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            pool.submit(task);
        }
        pool.awaitTermination(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        System.out.println("Task running...");
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: * // I have 4 cores, hyper-threaded... * That would be a better constant `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` :) and takes care if the process has not all CPUs affinity.

Comment: @bestsssL Will fix, thanks. This was a quick and dirty hack :)

Comment: now we know you are using an intel 1socket cpu based computer box.

Comment: @bestsss: You can find out a lot more about the machine I'm using on my blog :) http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/09/18/laptop-review-kobalt-g150.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll remember to post code in the future. I was actually blocking by using System.out.println() in my code, doh...

Answer (score 0):

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
for(int i=0; i < processors; i++) {
  Thread yourThread = new AThreadYouCreated();
  // You may need to pass in parameters depending on what work you are doing and how you          setup your thread.
  yourThread.start();
}
```

in this way you can solve your problem!